# Difference between TableRow and Row in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Which is the difference between TableRow and Row in flutter?
I checked that we have those 2 options, but don't know what I have to use and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Row` is analog of LinearLayout with horizontal orientation. `TableRow` is needed for creating a `Table` - you can see constructor of this class - [Table info](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html)

Comment: `Row` is horizontal `LinearLayout` not vertical.